# Lagrange multipliers numerical approach

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, constraints, numerical-methods

I have the following function that I'm trying to optimize that is subject to a constraint:

```
def damage(a, e, cr, cd):
    return 100*(1+a)*(1+e)*(1+cr*cd)

def constraint(a, e, cr, cd):
    return (100/0.466)*(a+e)+(100/0.622)*(2*cr+cd)
```

When solving for the Lagrangian by hand I get this output:

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as smp
a, e, c, d, l = smp.symbols('a e c d l')
eq1 = smp.Eq(1/(1+a), (100/46.6)*l)
eq2 = smp.Eq(1/(1+e), (100/46.6)*l)
eq3 = smp.Eq(d/(1+c*d), (100/62.2)*2*l)
eq4 = smp.Eq(c/(1+c*d), (100/62.2)*l)
eq5 = smp.Eq((100/46.6)*(a+e)+(100/62.2)*(2*c+d) - 300, 0)

solution = np.array(smp.solve([eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, eq5], [a, e, c, d, l]))
print(solution[0]/100)
print('Constraint', '{:,.0f}'.format(constraint(*(solution/100)[0][:-1])))
print('Max damage', '{:,.0f}'.format(float(round(damage(*(solution/100)[0][:-1])))))
```

> [0.344658405015485 0.344658405015485 0.236481193219279 0.472962386438559 0.000131394038153319]
> Constraint 300
> Max damage 201

To be able to solve this through a numerical approach, I modified the formulation of the problem by explicitly stating the constraints individually (separating the primary constraint into smaller constraints). I expressly stated the required relationships between the variables and constrained only one of the variables, which then determined the states of all of the other variables.

```
# We first convert this into a minimization problem.
from scipy import optimize
def damage_min(x):
    return -100*(1+x[0])*(1+x[1])*(1+x[2]*x[3])

# next we define the constrains (equal to 0)
def constraints(x):
    c1 = x[0] - x[1]
    c2 = 2*x[2] - x[3]
    c3 = x[0]/x[3] - 0.466/0.622
    c4 = x[3] - 0.466
    return np.array([c1, c2, c3, c4])
cons = ({'type': 'eq',
         'fun' : constraints})

# We solve the minimization problem
x_initial = np.array([34.4658405015485, 34.4658405015485, 23.6481193219279, 47.2962386438559])
solution = optimize.minimize(damage_min, x_initial, constraints=cons)
print(solution.x)
print('Constraint',  '{:,.0f}'.format(constraint(*(solution.x))))
print('Max damage', '{:,.0f}'.format(float(round(damage(*(solution.x))))))
```

> [0.3491254 0.3491254 0.233     0.466    ]
> Constraint 300
> Max damage 202

My question is as follows. How can I recreate the optimal results above by numerically optimizing a single function, e.g., the Lagrangian multiplier? When I try to put both functions into a single function, I get this output.

```
const = 300
def lagrangian(a, e, cr, cd, lam):
    return -damage(a, e, cr, cd) + lam*(round(constraint(a, e, cr, cd)) - const)

def vector_lagrangian(x):
    return lagrangian(x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4])

x_initial = np.array([32.4658405015485, 34.4658405015485, 23.6481193219279, 47.2962386438559, 1])
solution = optimize.minimize(vector_lagrangian, x_initial)

fun: -2.140132414183526e+37
 hess_inv: array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
      jac: array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
  message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     nfev: 119
      nit: 1
     njev: 17
   status: 0
  success: True
        x: array([ 6.90178344e+08,  6.51257507e+08,  9.75839219e+08,  4.87919645e+08,
       -5.08835272e+06])
'constraint': '680,080,111,963'
```

The constraint, in this case, isn't being held and it converges on a local minimum. Why is this the case? Is the problem caused by the solver, the specific function that is being optimized, or is there some other reason?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow")! Questions that ask for general guidance regarding a problem approach are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a correct answer. Give a good read over [Where to Start](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367), and  [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") then edit your post.

Comment: I'd say the question is quite specific. I'm running the optimization through the numeric approach and am getting incorrect results. I want to know why the constraint isn't being held for this specific case. 
Meanwhile, the results can be reproduced by running the functions above there is nothing additional linked here.
Finally, further questions are always welcome. I don't mind elaborating on the details if needed.

Comment: Your question as stated is "Does anyone know if what it is that this solver isn't doing?".  There is no specific "correct" answer which can address this question.  Therefore the question can only be answered by opinions.

Comment: @itprorh66 I agree that the question should be a bit more focused and reduced. However, I disagree that the question can only be answered by opinions. There's a simple reason the solver doesn't yield the correct solution: OP's math is wrong.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, your math is wrong since minimizing the Lagrangian doesn't yield a local minimum of the corresponding optimization problem. Assuming f : R^n -> R and g : R^n -> R^m are both differentiable functions and you want to solve the optimization problem

```
min f(x) s.t. g(x) = 0
```

then the first-order necessary optimality condition (FOC) is

```
∇L(x, λ) = ∇f(x) + ∇g(x)^T * λ = 0
                          g(x) = 0
```

where L is the Lagrangian, ∇f the objective gradient and ∇g the transposed Jacobian of the function g. Consequently, you need to find a root of the function H(x,λ) = (∇f(x) + λ^T * ∇g(x), g(x))^T to solve the FOC, which can be done by means of [`scipy.optimize.root`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root.html):

```py
from scipy.optimize import minimize, root
from scipy.optimize._numdiff import approx_derivative

def damage_min(x):
    return -100*(1+x[0])*(1+x[1])*(1+x[2]*x[3])

def constraints(x):
    c1 = x[0] - x[1]
    c2 = 2*x[2] - x[3]
    c3 = x[0]/x[3] - 0.466/0.622
    c4 = x[3] - 0.466
    return np.array([c1, c2, c3, c4])

def f_grad(x):
    return approx_derivative(damage_min, x)

def g_jac(x):
    return approx_derivative(constraints, x)

def H(z, f_grad, g, g_jac):
    g_evaluated = g(z)
    x, λ   = np.split(z, (-g_evaluated.size, ))
    eq1 = f_grad(x) + g_jac(x).T @ λ
    eq2 = g_evaluated
    return np.array([*eq1, *eq2])

# res.x contains the solution
res = root(lambda z: H(z, f_grad, constraints, g_jac), x0=np.ones(8))
```

which yields the solution (consisting of x and the lagrangian multipliers λ):

```py
array([ 3.49125402e-01,  3.49125402e-01,  2.33000000e-01,  4.66000000e-01,
       -1.49561074e+02,  4.24092469e+01,  1.39390921e+02,  3.08919653e+02])
```

A few notes:

- In general, it's highly recommended to provide exact derivatives instead of approximating them by finite differences by means of `approx_derivate`.
- If you **really** want to solve a minimization problem, you can solve the FOC by minimizing the euclidean norm of the function H. This is exactly what the `root` method does under the hood.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear explanation. Using the function H is an excellent way of combining conditions from the Lagrangian. approx_derivate is also very powerful. In my case, I plan to provide the exact derivatives for the gradient from the natural logarithm of the objective function. As far as I understand, the monotonic transformation woun't create new issues with the gradient. Meanwhile, given that most of the constraints are going to be linear in nature, hopefully, the finite difference approximation that approx_derivate uses under the hood will suffice.